# Postgres search for date that can return 2-6-1992 on searching 2/6/1992

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have text type search field where user can write anything i.e. ID, Name or Date

I am generating sql for search, which is working fine. 
But for date it is selecting record having date_of_birth: 02-06-1992 only if I search in a specific sequence i.e. `1992-06-02` or `02-06`

```
def search_patient(search)
  " (
    (first_name ILIKE '#{search}%' )
    OR
    (last_name ILIKE '#{search}%' )
    OR
    (id.value = '#{search}' )
    OR
    CAST(date_of_birth AS varchar) like '%#{search}%'
  ) "
end
```

I want to do something that 2/6/1992 could return 02-06-1992, Is there any date searching function which allows me to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply check if the text in the search field is a valid date or not. Then you can add your date query in your main query.

```
def search_patient(search)
  date_term = DateTime.parse search rescue nil
  dob_query = ''
  if date_term
    dob_query = " OR
                (CAST(date_of_birth AS varchar) = '#{search}')"
  end

  " (
      (first_name ILIKE '#{search}%')
      OR
      (last_name ILIKE '#{search}%')
      OR
      (id.value = '#{search}')
      #{dob_query}
   ) "
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you leave the datatype of `date_of_birth` to `date`. Then the query could be like this:

```
def search_patient(search)
  Patient.where( "first_name ILIKE ? OR last_name ILIKE ? OR id.value = ? OR Date.parse(date_of_birth) = ?",
                 "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", Date.parse("%#{search}%"))
end
```

Comment: It is showing error as follow:
`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::InvalidSchemaName: ERROR:  schema "date" does not exist` 
`LINE 28:         (Date.parse(date_of_birth) = Date.parse('1/1'))
`